# Embedding HTML5 video in ArcGIS Story Map Series?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map, video

It appears that the Story Map Series only allows an iframe for inserting videos. Although, I cannot use YouTube or other hosting services so the link is directly to the video instead of a video host. I would like to simply embed HTML5 instead, which I attempted below.

First I created the html file containing this:

```
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="url_to_my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Then I included the following iframe in the story map.

```
<iframe src="url_to_my_file.html" />
```

The video never appeared. Any ideas?

Comment: you need some javascript see video.js https://developerscorner.storymaps.arcgis.com/a-simple-way-to-host-videos-for-story-maps-2b73874289e4